# how to retrieve specific tag information using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I would like to retrieve specific tag attribute.
`file` tag contains child tag `filename` and basing on this field I would like to decide if the `modification` should be taken.

In other words: if `filename` value contains `.tar` I would like to print modification time.

In example below I'd expect that `2020-07-15T06:41:12.000Z` would be printed.

I was trying to do this for 2 hours but I did not succed, so I'll be really thankful for any tips bringing me closer to the solution.
Here is the code, but nothing is printed nor added to `dates` list:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r"C:\path\to\file\logs.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
dates = []
for filetag in root.findall('.//{*}file'):
    for filename in filetag.findall('../{*}filename'):
        if ".tar" in filename.attrib['value']:
            print(filename)
            dates.append(filename)
```

Here is XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="user@11.11.111.11" start="2020-07-22T10:01:12.939Z">
  <ls>
    <destination value="/folder/processing" />
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value="." />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2020-07-22T08:57:28.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrwsrwx" />
        <owner value="1000130000" />
        <group value="0" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value=".." />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2020-07-22T08:51:15.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrwxrwx" />
        <owner value="1000130000" />
        <group value="0" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="package_tsp200715092001_20200715074120.tar" />
        <type value="-" />
        <size value="4014536192" />
        <modification value="2020-07-15T06:41:12.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rw-rw-rw-" />
        <owner value="1005" />
        <group value="1005" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="package_tsp200715092001_20200715074120" />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2020-07-15T06:41:59.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxr-Sr--" />
        <owner value="1000130000" />
        <group value="0" />
      </file>
    </files>
    <result success="true" />
  </ls>
</session>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for filename in filetag.findall('../{*}filename'):
> ```

because of the `..` this looks for a `filename` in the *parent* of the `file` element (that is, as a sibling of `file`). It should be a single `.`

Furthermore, *namespace* wildcards were added in Python 3.8. You don't indicate which Python version you're using, so this may also be an issue.

Anyway you're probably better off "properly" using namespaces instead of looking for shortcuts, it's a bit more verbose but hardly *difficult*:

```py
NS = {'scp': 'http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0'}
for filetag in root.findall('.//scp:file', NS):
    for filename in filetag.findall('./scp:filename', NS):
        if ".tar" in filename.get('value', ''):
            print(filename)
            dates.append(filename)
```

Comment: I've just noticed, that I made mistake, saving the `filename` instead of `modification`. How in this situation should I edit `print(filename)` in order to print proper date? In other words: how to print `modification` tag of parent `file` if sibling of `filename`(which is `modification`) contains `.tar`?

Comment: You can use `Element.find` to get the `modification` child of the `file` element. In fact you could also do that for `filename` as there's only one, iteration is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a one liner:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''

<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="user@11.11.111.11" start="2020-07-22T10:01:12.939Z">
  <ls>
    <destination value="/folder/processing" />
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value="." />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2020-07-22T08:57:28.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrwsrwx" />
        <owner value="1000130000" />
        <group value="0" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value=".." />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2020-07-22T08:51:15.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrwxrwx" />
        <owner value="1000130000" />
        <group value="0" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="package_tsp200715092001_20200715074120.tar" />
        <type value="-" />
        <size value="4014536192" />
        <modification value="2020-07-15T06:41:12.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rw-rw-rw-" />
        <owner value="1005" />
        <group value="1005" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="package_tsp200715092001_20200715074120" />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2020-07-15T06:41:59.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxr-Sr--" />
        <owner value="1000130000" />
        <group value="0" />
      </file>
    </files>
    <result success="true" />
  </ls>
</session>
'''

NS = {'scp': 'http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0'}
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
tar_files_dates = [f.find('./scp:modification',NS).attrib['value'] for f in root.findall('.//scp:file',NS) if '.tar' in f.find('./scp:filename',NS).attrib['value']]
print(tar_files_dates)
```

output

```
['2020-07-15T06:41:12.000Z']
```